# React, Spring: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check cors error while trying to send post request

Tags: reactjs, spring, axios, cors, fetch

I'm trying to send request from react frontend to authenticate user on my spring-boot backend, but I still get an error
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/auth/authenticate' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.`
I think that my backend cors configuration shouldn't be a problem. I've done it with help of [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors)

This is my cors configuration:

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:5173");
            }
        };
    }
```

And I'm trying to send request this way:

```
await axios.post(
      "http://localhost:8080/auth/authenticate",
      {
        email: email,
        password: password,
      },
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        withCredentials: true
      }
    );
```

I was trying to modify my cors config by adding allowed methods. Also before I've been using fetchAPI to make this request.
Everything works fine, when I send request without `withCredentials` parameter, but I need to retrieve jwt token which is sent from backend via httpOnly Set-Cookie header.

Comment: Your CORS configuration (`allowedOrigins("http://localhost:5173")`) is insufficient. You need to modify it to also allow request header `Content-Type` and allow credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @jub0bs said, my cors configuration was insufficient. In the end it should look like this:

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:5173")
                        .allowCredentials(true);
            }
        };
    }
```